# BigQuery ST_SIMPLIFY returns GEOMETRYCOLLECTION instead of POLYGON

Tags: google-bigquery

I found one issue in BigQuery function ST_SIMPLIFY.

I'm querying big geometries and some stats for them. In case I need to visualize them e.g. in Kepler it is not possible because Kepler do not consume output from BigQuery ST_SIMPLIFY. I analyzed results from ST_SIMPLIFY and found this:

As an input that I used is in all cases POLYGON parsed from OSM.
[image]

When I call ST_SIMPLIFY I get results of mixed geometry types like POLYGON and GEOMETRYCOLLECTION containing MULTILINESTRINGs, LINESTRINGs, POLYGONs.

[image]

Maybe it is not so strange but when I tried to visualize these geometries, they do not make sense. Especially LINESTRINGs inside GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONs like in this [geojson](https://gist.github.com/cechovsky/0f33c4bb0ef8e44b997e9ed28e3b80be)

When I tried use these geometries in [simplify function in Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.simplify) I got valid results containing only POLYGONs

Why BigQuery ST_SIMPLIFY returns GEOMETRYCOLLECTIONS with geom mixed types instead of simple one POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON?

To reproduce this issue you can init BQ table from these [data](https://gist.github.com/cechovsky/d2edee5cc19e0a20f9e9bd062fb72c18)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When simplifying, BigQuery can reduce dimensions of the shape if the lower dimension shape represents the original shape with requested precision.

E.g.

```
with data as (
select st_geogfromtext(
'polygon((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1.5 2, 1.5 3, 1.499 2, 1 2, 1 1))') g
)
select g, st_simplify(g, 10000) s from data
```

Here the "spike" at the top of the shape is converted into a line, and we get
`GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(1.5 2, 1.5 3), POLYGON((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1.5 2, 1 2, 1 1)))`.

Use

```
with data as (
select st_geogfromtext(
'polygon((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1.5 2, 1.5 3, 1.499 2, 1 2, 1 1))') g
)
select st_union(st_dump(st_simplify(g, 10000),2)) s from data
```

to extract polygon only if you are OK with ignoring such spikes.

Comment: great answer, thanks a lot. Still I'm surprised why Simplify methods from other libraries (like Shapely or PostGIS) works in another way, but now BQ is usable more for me

Answer (score 1):

I wrote BigQuery function that solved my issue. Basically this function ignore all geometries except POLYGON and MULTIPOLYGON. Tested results are possible to visualize in Kepler and other tools

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  my_project.repair_simplified_geom(geom ANY TYPE) AS ((
    SELECT
      ST_UNION(ARRAY_AGG(geom))
    FROM
      UNNEST(ST_DUMP(geom)) AS geom
    WHERE
      STARTS_WITH(ST_ASTEXT(geom), 'POLYGON')
      OR STARTS_WITH(ST_ASTEXT(geom), 'MULTIPOLYGON')))
```

Usage

```
select my_project.repair_simplified_geom(ST_SIMPLIFY(geometry,100)) as geom from
`admin_levels_svk.admin_levels_3_svk`
```

Comment: you can use `ST_Dump(geom, 2)` to select only 2d objects (i.e. polygons) and avoid parsing.

Comment: This is the second time I have been caught out by BiqQuery being a bit different to Postgis. It took me a while to find the ST_MakeValid is in fact a switch in ST_GeogFromText and now I discover that ST_CollectionExtract is implemented as a parameter in ST_Dump :-)